# a combinatoric limit proof

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $\beta >4$. Prove that if
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k{n\choose k}{n\choose {k-1}}$$
then
$$\lim_{n=0}\frac{a_n}{\beta^n} = 0$$
**My attempt to solve it:**

I tried to show that $a_n \leq 4^n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n\choose k}3^k$ (by derivating the binomial identity) so what I actually need to show is that ${n\choose {k-1}} \leq 3^k$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$, and here I got stuck.

Any help in showing this or a completely different solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{eqnarray}a_n &=&\sum_{k=0}^{n}k{n\choose k}{n\choose {k-1}}\\&=&n\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n-1\choose k-1}{n\choose {k-1}}\\
&=&n\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n-1\choose n-k}{n\choose {k-1}}\\
&=&n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.
\end{eqnarray}$$ Since it holds by binomial theorem that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}kx^{k-1}=2n(1+x)^{2n-1},
$$we have (by letting $x=1$)
$$
0\le 2a_n = n\binom{2n}{n}\le 2n\cdot 2^{2n-1}=n\cdot 4^n.
$$ For $\beta>4$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{\beta^n}\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{4}{\beta}\right)^n = 0.
$$

Comment: why is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n-1}\choose{k-n}}{n\choose {k-1}} = {{2n-1}\choose{n-1}}$?

Comment: @RoboYonuomaro It can be obtained by comparing coefficients of $z^{n−1}$ on both sides of
$$(1+z)^{n−1}(1+z)^n=(1+z)^{2n−1}.$$ And there is a typo: it should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n-1}\choose{n-k}}{n\choose {k-1}} =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{{n-1}\choose{n-k-1}}{n\choose {k}} = {{2n-1}\choose{n-1}}.$

Comment: 1) It is a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). 2) I cannot see any typo (may be it was corrected). 2) All these sums should start at $k=1$, not $k=0$. 3) +1 ;-)